# Data Table Select Operation causing index corruption

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am working with a web service where many operations should populate data from the database. In order to avoid concurrent calls to the database, I have created a class with a static datatable variable, my methods will perform select operation on the datatable to get user name, through filtering by user code.
Occasionally and randomly, the invoked webmethods returns an ERROR400 (bad request) to the client, the error is "The exception message is 'DataTable internal index is corrupted: '5'".
I have researched the issue, but unfortunately, most topics treat the  manipulation (add/modify/delete rows) of the datatable in an multithreaded environment, while my operations only consist of select operations on the datatable.
Please find below the code that fills the datatable, (which is theoretically going to fill the datatable once, across all web method calls, since once the datatable is filled,  the "if (DtName == "dtUsers" && dtUsers ==null)" condition will prevent re-filling).

```
  public static DataTable dtUsers;
     public static void InitialiseData(string DtName)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new MongoClient(EMRWS.MongoConstr);
                var db = client.GetDatabase(EMRWS.MongoDB);
                DataRow dr1;
                if (DtName == "dtUsers" && dtUsers ==null)
                {
                    var usercol = db.GetCollection<Cls_Users>("tbl_Users");
                    dtUsers = new DataTable();
                    dtUsers.Columns.Add("usercode", typeof(string));
                    dtUsers.Columns.Add("username", typeof(string));
                    dtUsers.Columns.Add("usertype", typeof(string));
                    dtUsers.Columns.Add("usersubtype", typeof(string));
                    usercol.AsQueryable().ToList().ForEach
                    (
                    p =>
                    {
                        dr1 = dtUsers.NewRow();
                        dr1["usercode"] = p.User_Code;
                        dr1["username"] = p.User_Name;
                        dr1["usertype"] = p.User_Type;
                        dr1["usersubtype"] = p.User_SubType;
                        dtUsers.Rows.Add(dr1);
                    }
                    );
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `DataTable` should not be stored in a `static`. It isn't thread-safe for writes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_12

Comment: But write operation is performed only once, all the other operations are datatable.select(filterExpression)

Comment: Are the selects occurring while the write is occurring?

Comment: Unless the datatable is filled more than once, and this condition ("if (DtName == "dtUsers" && dtUsers ==null)") does not prevent refilling the data table across many AJAX calls, the write does not occur while writing.

Comment: `does not prevent refilling the data table across many AJAX calls` It does not prevent it. You would need a `lock` or something similar to do that.